# Find first blank cell in a row and return corresponding column number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working with a dataset that looks like this:

|  | 1967 | 1968 | 1969 | 1970 | 1971 | 1972 | 1973 | 1974 | 1975 | 1976 | 1977 | 1978 | 1979 | 1980 | 1981 | 1982 | 1983 | 1984 | Data start date | First data gap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 1967 | NA |
| B | 1 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 3 |  |  |  |  | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 1967 | 1972 |
| C |  |  |  |  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 1971 | NA |
| D |  |  |  | 1 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |  |  |  |  |  | 4 | 7 | 9 | 10 | 1970 | 1976 |

I want to write formulas that return the values in the columns "Data start year" and "First data gap".

Data start year should simply return the year in which the data starts, e.g. 1971 for C.

First data gap should return the year in which the **first data gap after the start of the data**. In the cases of B and D these would be 1972 and 1976, respectively.

I have tried several approaches online but nothing seems to work. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `T2`:

```
=BYROW(B2:S5,LAMBDA(r,@FILTER(B1:S1,r)))
```

---

[image]

Formula in `U2`:

```
=MAP(A2:A5,T2#,LAMBDA(x,y,@FILTER(B1:S1,(B1:S1>y)*(XLOOKUP(x,A2:A5,B2:S5)=""),"NA")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative which uses <kbd>BYROW( )</kbd> , <kbd>FILTER( )</kbd> & <kbd>XLOOKUP( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>T2</kbd>

```
=BYROW(B2:S5,LAMBDA(x,XLOOKUP(1,1/(x<>""),B1:S1)))
```

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>U2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     x,B1:S1,
     y,B2:S5,
       BYROW(y,LAMBDA(α,@FILTER(
       XLOOKUP(1,(α<>"")/1,x):
       XLOOKUP(1,(α<>"")/1,x,,,-1),
       XLOOKUP(1,(α<>"")/1,α):
       XLOOKUP(1,(α<>"")/1,α,,,-1)=0,
     "NA"))))
```

---

**Note:** that the second formula is not dependent on the **Data Start Column**